# how to plot a raster file as a histogram using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, raster

I have a raster file
 and I want to plot as a histogram ,i did it using hist() as shown below. but i would like to plot using ggplot2 which plot it in a better way for publication.

```
conne <- file("C:\\fined.bin","rb")
r = raster(y)
hist(r, breaks=30, main="SMD_2010",
        xlab="Pearson correlation", ylab="Frequency", xlim=c(-1,1))
```

I tried this:

```
  qplot(rating, data=r, geom="histogram")
```

Error:

```
            ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class RasterLayer
```

I need to plot something like:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_histogram-28.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a fast solution You can use the result of `hist`

```
f <- hist(r, breaks=30)
dat <- data.frame(counts= f$counts,breaks = f$mids)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = breaks, y = counts)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill='blue',alpha = 0.8)+
  xlab("Pearson correlation")+ ylab("Frequency")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,1,0.25),  ## without this you will get the same scale
                   labels = seq(-1,1,0.25))    ## as hist (question picture)
```

PS : Maybe you need to use `scale_x_discrete` to get better axis look

**EDIT** to add gradient fill

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = breaks, y = counts, fill =counts)) + ## Note the new aes fill here
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",alpha = 0.8)+
  xlab("Pearson correlation")+ ylab("Frequency")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,1,0.25),
                   labels = seq(-1,1,0.25))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")            ## to play with colors limits
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If your object `r` is a `rasterLayer` object, then I think you just need to convert it to data frame, maybe this:

```
rr <- as.data.frame(values(r))
```

See `?getValues` as you might need a slight variation in that call.  In any case, `ggplot2` must take a data frame as its data source.

Looking a bit closer, I think this does what you want, but it's actually simpler if don't convert to a `rasterLayer` object but instead plot your `y` object.  But I'm not able to play with the file you link to (probably my error) so you'll have to try it out.

EDIT: Here's an example that works:

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
r <- raster(f)
rr <- as.data.frame(r)
str(rr)
# data is in one particular slot:
qplot(rr$test)
```

FURTHER DETAILS:

```
str(rr)
'data.frame':   9200 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ test: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

summary(rr)
      test       
 Min.   : 128.4  
 1st Qu.: 293.2  
 Median : 371.4  
 Mean   : 423.2  
 3rd Qu.: 499.8  
 Max.   :1805.8  
 NA's   :6097
```

[image: Histogram of rr$test]

If this is not working for you, I'm up on `2013-01-21 r61719` which is the 3.0 RC.  Maybe that's the difference?  `ggplot2 0.9.3`?

Comment: @Bryan ..whent I test your solution I get an error. and really what do you mean by rr$test?

Comment: @Barry `qplot` tries to read your mind as much as possible.  With `qplot(rr$test)` it looks at `rr$test` and tries to select a geom and x and y values.  `rr$test` is a vector so it goes to geom histogram automatically.  In your command, you gave it almost everything, so it's not going to try to guess, just give it x too: `qplot(data = rr, x = test, geom = "histogram")`

Comment: @agstudy `str(rr)` gives `'data.frame': 9200 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ test: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...` What error do you get?

Comment: @BryanHanson I get the same thing ..my test is all NA...how you can get a histogram with this? ..can you add please the plot do you have to the answer?

Comment: With my raster I had to use `unlist`, e.g., `summary(unlist(as.data.frame(raster$value)))` where `value` is the name of the data frame column.